# High throughput NoSQL Databases

Tags: database, performance, throughput, bigdata, nosql

Iam looking for a suitable Database for a System that should be able to handle 100.000 writes per minute. And also random reads from users.
Data should be about 100 bytes each write.
Now i checked some Benchmarks of NoSQL Databases. One of them from [Datastax](http://www.datastax.com/apache-cassandra-leads-nosql-benchmark)

It shows in many cases different performance tests for read, write and mixed operations. for HBase, Cassandra, Couchbase and MongoDB.

In most cases i need like 12 nodes to do 100.000+ operations per second.

Do i need to have the ability to handle all requests per second, if i have 100.000 operations per minute? Eventually it could happen that all requests are sent in one second? If i had 100.000 writes per second. Would that mean that every read from a webapplication would need more than 1 second.
I iam a little bit confused.

EDIT:
I Dont want you to choose a database for me.If i had really 100.000 writes every minute, should my database be able to handle my requests in one second? And would that mean i need like more than 12 node to have a good performance?

Comment: Recommendations are outside the scope of Stack Overflow.  But, 100,000 writes per second is not a big load; that's less than 2,000/second.

Comment: with how many nodes of a distributed database?

Comment: According to this comparison (https://www.sqlite.org/speed.html) ancient software on archaic single-processor hardware beats 2,000 inserts/second.

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest you, if you need 100.000 Ops/Sec according to Cassandra Documentations this is a good Database to do that only with two nodes you can handle that see the picture below:

[image]

With 12 nodes, you can do more than that if you have the right partitioning, right replication factor and other stuffs.

But this can easily solve your problem.

But, if you are having a problem of 100.000 per minute... Go with a MySQL or a Postgres. That will solve your problem.

Comment: Please don't answer such off-topic product recommendation questions. You could name just about *any* database as an answer, and it would be just as valid (or invalid). And then following up with some SQL recommendations? That doesn't even make sense, and there's no way to know that any of them will solve the op's problem.